# color a line with a clipping mask illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

[image]Im trying to color a line using a clipping mask but the only thing I get is to affect the saturation of the line, not the color.

Is there any option or way that doesn't involve going to every single line and coloring it individually?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why is there a clipping mask? Why can't you just color the paths as you want?

Comment: I didnt wanted to go to every line to colored it invidually, Is like in photoshop You can put an image or something and then a shape with color over that and  use mutiply or color and the colors will change i dont know if im explain myself

Comment: In Illustrator you can select all the lines and color them as one thing, you don't need any masks. You can even group them and apply a color to the group.. or change blending modes of the group. I think it's probably the unnecessary mask which may be causing you issues (but honestly I can't tell from what you've posted here)

Comment: @Metis what's the easiest way to select the lines / strokes? I'd bet that would solve this for her/him.

Comment: `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` *might* work.. but again.. it's **really** difficult to say without understanding how any mask is applied. I can't tell by looking at the posted image. It is not impossible that the lines **are** the mask.. which will cause all sorts of headaches.

Comment: maybe this way it will show more

Comment: Oh.. It does show more.... the color image is your mask.... so only the line luminosity will change (based upon the luminosity of the mask image), not color. I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve now. If you want the lines to take on the color of the mask image, you have things backwards. You want the lines to *be the mask* and the color image to be the artwork. But even in this case, the lines won't change color.. they'll take on the image's color.

Comment: Opacity masks read *opacity* they won't read color. There's no way to use an Opacity Mask to change the color of something, they *only* change opacity (which may appear to be luminosity). And you have an **opacity mask**, not a clipping mask. They are two different things.

Comment: I see ty! Now I have it as I wanted

Comment: And on a tangential note, why do anime characters always have rabbit ears? Or whatever those are.

Comment: its for my friend who is an streamer she has pikachus theme so I added some pikachus ears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any option or way that doesn't involve going to every single line and coloring it individually?

Yes.

Here I have a few shapes with different fill colors and different shades of black for strokes:

[image: Different color shapes and strokes]

Select all of the artwork (objects, groups or layers) you wish to affect and hit the **Recolor Artwork** button:

[image: Recolor Artwork Button]

When the dialog opens, you'll see all of the colors in your current selection... Make sure that 'Recolor Art' is checked to preview your changes:

[image: recolor Artwork dialog box]

Notice the empty spot beside the blacks... Click on that empty spot and choose 'Yes' when prompted:

[image: Click Yes]

Now make sure your color(s) are highlighted (in blue as below) and double-click here on the blacks (or whichever color you wish to alter):

[image: Double-click here]

Now choose your replacement color and click 'OK' twice to accept the changes. And the result:

[image: Only the stroke has been affected]

Note that only the strokes have been altered.

Comment: OMG you are awesome! ty very much!